# How to manage AsyncTask and need for dialog

Tags: android, ssh, dialog, android-asynctask, fingerprint

I'm pretty new to Android development, in the later states of my first serious project.  Briefly, the program will ssh into a Linux host and perform commands.  But I find myself really getting tied into knots trying to finish this.

I'm using ganymed-ssh2 to do the ssh grunt-work.

When an Activity button is hit, I want the program to start a SSH session, verify the host fingerprint - prompting for acceptance if necessary, and then issue remote commands as programed.  But this seemingly simple few steps, are getting very complicated by the following:

1. The ssh cannot be performed in the UI thread, so I have to start an AsyncTask, so all of what I describe in the next hassles are not in the foreground UI thread.
2. To activate the ssh fingerprinting code, I need to make a call like this inside my AsyncTask class:

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... command) {
       String result;
   result = "";
   try {
     /* Create a connection instance */            
         Connection conn = new Connection(connect.getHost(), connect.getPort());

     /* Now connect */
     ConnectionInfo info = conn.connect(new AdvancedVerifier());

         boolean isAuthenticated = false;
     // first try public key if defined
     if (connect.getPrivateKey() != null)
     isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPublicKey
            (connect.getUserid(), connect.getPrivateKey(), null);  
     // if failed, or not defined, try password if provide
         if (!isAuthenticated && connect.getPassword() != null)
     isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(connect.getUserid(), 
                new String (connect.getPassword()));

         // all else, get out
         if (!isAuthenticated)
           throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

     /* Create a session */
         Session sess = conn.openSession();
         sess.execCommand(command[0]);
   }
   ```

However, the conn.connect(new AdvancedVerifier()) line causes a callback interface class of AdvancedVerifier to be called, interrupting the execution path at the connect call to call this class:

```
    class AdvancedVerifier implements ServerHostKeyVerifier
    {
        public boolean verifyServerHostKey(String hostname, int port, 
          String serverHostKeyAlgorithm,
          byte[] serverHostKey) throws Exception
        {
            final String host = hostname;
            final String algo = serverHostKeyAlgorithm;

            /* Check database   - code removed*/
            /* assuming fingerprint needs verification */

            String hexFingerprint =
                KnownHosts.createHexFingerprint(serverHostKeyAlgorithm,
                    serverHostKey);

            String msg = "Hex Fingerprint: " + hexFingerprint;

            /* right here, I need to display dialog of fingerprint, 
               and ask user for to continue;
               If user accepts, return true, else return false.

               If return true, the above class continues after connect(), if false
               it is aborted.
            */
            return UserAccepts? true : false;
       }
     }
```

Well this, in my limited experience, seems to raise lots of truely messy code.
First, I need to reattach back to the UI thread, display a dialog, then if user selects
OK, to then return "true" from verifyServerHostKey(), detach UI thread, and allow the ssh connection code to resume.  All without the ability to use modal dialogs.
Frankly, I don't really know where to begin and am looking for ideas, guidance, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out at least one way to solve the problem.  Using a wait/notify combination between my AdvancedVerifier class and using a AlertDialog in onProgressUpdate, I was able to pause the verifier class while the user accepts/rejects the host fingerprint.

Don't know if there is a better way, but I think I can work with this.